# How to create an hidden overflow in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I **really** need to create an overflow in Xamarin Forms. How can I achieve this?

My particular use case: I need to programmatically add children in an horizontal direction, and they have to be clipped at the end of te window so I can programmatically show them translating the parent.

I have tried all of the layouts but all of them just fill their parent. 
I tried also the IsClippedToBounds property applied to the parent but neither that works. 
Is it just so difficult to create in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what you're trying to archive and the code you try so far. But if i understand you right, seems you need an horizontal listview

Comment: yes, that is the behavior but I need to scroll it vertically and disable horizontal scroll. Then I will programmatically translate its content.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Flex Layout? Below code, will give you horizontal orientation and it's wrap once horizontally filled. And the list goes vertically after filling each row.

```
 <Grid>
    <ScrollView>
        <FlexLayout x:Name="flexLayout" Direction="Row"
                    Wrap="Wrap"
                    JustifyContent="SpaceAround"  />
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

You can see a demo and working code [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/FlexLayoutDemos/)

Comment: I don't need to wrap the horizontal, instead I need that it continues over the bounds. Then I don't need It is scrollable horizontally, is there a way to disable horizontal scrolling and scroll it programmatically?

Comment: May I know your purpose or exact requirement?